# $\ln x\approx 2\cdot \dfrac {x-1}{x+1}$, for $x\approx 1$ , How does one show this result?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, taylor-expansion

Where does this result come from: I saw it when viewing Andrew Woods answer on this post: [What is the best way to calculate log without a calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820094/what-is-the-best-way-to-calculate-log-without-a-calculator).

I thought one would be able to derive it from the Taylor expansion:

$\ln \left( 1+\varepsilon \right) =\varepsilon -\dfrac {\varepsilon ^{2}}{2}$ + ...

Set $X = 1+\varepsilon $

$\ln \left( X\right) =X-1-\dfrac {\left( X-1\right) ^{2}}{2}$+...

but that does not seem to work?

Comment: See also: [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padé_approximant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $x=1+y$ so $y\ll 1$ and $$2\frac{x-1}{x+1}=\frac{y}{1+y/2}\approx y-y^2/2\approx\ln(1+y)=\ln x.$$