# Anti Logarithm Formula

Tags: logarithms

Is there any formula to calculate anti logarithm just using simple calculator.. I already know how to calculate logarithm digit by digit exactly just like this [What is the best way to calculate log without a calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820094/what-is-the-best-way-to-calculate-log-without-a-calculator) But how to calculate the antilog like antilog(0.456)=10^0.456=2.857590 using simple calculator..

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! By antilogarithm you mean [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) ?

Comment: See https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-calculate-log-and-anti-log-on-a-normal-calculator

Comment: I think they mean the function that is the inverse of, for example: $\log_{10}(100)=2\rightarrow\text{antilog}_{10}(2)=100$

Comment: I mean calculate the anti logarithm with accurate answer not just approximation.. like antilog (0.456) = 10^0.456 just calculate using simple calculator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Taylor polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem). In case of function $f(x)=10^x,$ you have
$$f(x)=1+x\ln10+\frac{(x\ln10)^2}{2!}+\frac{(x\ln10)^3}{3!}+\frac{(x\ln10)^4}{4!}+\cdots$$
For a decent approximation, it is usually enough to use first 6 or 7 elements of the series. In this particular case
$$10^{0.456}\approx1+.456*2.3026+\frac{(.456*2.3026)^2}{2}+\frac{(.456*2.3026)^3}{6}+\frac{(.456*2.3026)^4}{24}+\frac{(.456*2.3026)^5}{120}+\frac{(.456*2.3026)^6}{720}=2.8572\ldots$$

Another idea that comes to mind is using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

[edit]

Calculating $a^b$ using Newton's method would look like this:

**Step 1:** Choose an initial value (your best guess) $x_0$

**Step 2:** Calculate $x_{n+1}=x_n-(\log_a x_0-b)x_0\ln a$

**Step 3:** Repeat step 2 until satisfied with the approximation.

Your example:

$$x_0=3$$
$$x_1=3-(\log 3-0.456)3\ln 10=2.8541$$
$$x_2=2.8541-(\log 2.8541-0.456)2.8541\ln 10=2.85759$$

This method requires fewer steps to achieve the same precision level but the steps are more complex, especially if you are calculating the logarithms by hand (or using a simple calculator).

Comment: Are there other formula? Cause it pretty difficult to calculate it with simple calculator.. and its not really accurate just using 6-7 terms for 3 decimal accuracy.

Comment: @Evilangel See the edit which describes Newton's method in more detail. I don't know any faster and simpler method. The idea with Taylor polynomial is basically what calculators use for calculating powers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. so I have to calculate every new log using the method I give on the link.. and can't calculate using simple calculator in one time calculation..

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm a little late to the party, but if you need a simple way to calculate a **rough** approximation of antilog base 10, use the following procedure:

1. Separate the integer part from the fractional part.  So 1.3979 is split into 1 and 0.3979.
2. Use the fractional part on this formula:
   5.5x^3+  x^2 + 2.5x + 1
   So in this example, 5.5(0.3979^3) + 0.3979^2 + 2.5(0.3979) + 1
   which equals: 2.499 or 2.5 with a little rounding.
3. Now write the answer and then E and then the integer part of the original number.
   So we get 2.5E1 which is short for 2.5x10^1 or 25.

If you aren't looking for exact values and just need to be in the ballpark, this formula will usually do.  If you are making some kind of graphics program where speed is more important than accuracy, then this is what you want.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).